# separate all the similar options to text boxes from select javascript

Tags: javascript, html

hello friends i need a small help regarding separation of options from select

```
    <html>
<select> 
 <option> mango</option>
 <option> apple</option>
 <option> apple</option>
 <option> grapes</option>
 <option> mango</option>
 <option> grapes</option>
</select>
</html>
```

i want to seperate all mangoes to one textbox and apples to another and so on... dynamically

please helpme with the code... thank you

Comment: what do you mean by separate, show the expected output.

Comment: separate similar options (mangoes to textbox1, grapes to textbox2....) to each text box.

Comment: It's still unclear to me, specify the whole scenario, you wan to do it in selecting an element, or on window load, & textboxes are static or they will be crated dynamically.

Comment: In short to what @Mritunjay has said. What `event` do you want to do to be able to seperate those options. `onchange` ? `onload` ? etc...

Comment: text box should be created dynamically and separate the options into each text box

Comment: thank you @Alexdn I want this to be done by onload event.

Comment: do yo need to create individual textbox for all the values in the select box, like 2 textbox for mango, 2 for grape etc....

Comment: similar values goes into one textbox ( eg:all mango value goes to one textbox,grapes option to another textbox and so on )

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle for you. here it is: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/frLdf32L/95/)

Thanks for SO friends that help me. BTW, for me to achieve what you want, If you notice, I store all values taken from `option` tag to an **array**. Then make again a new **array** to store the filtered duplicate values. And for final step is to `append` a `textbox` that has a value of those three. here's some of the codes:

```
var x = document.getElementById("fruits");
var getfruits = [];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x.options[i].text;
    var y = x.options[i].text;
    getfruits.push(y);
}
```

**EDITED:**

I add here some of fruits to see more effectiveness. You can also add some as you want. **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/frLdf32L/102/)**

**NOTE:** If you want to use `value` of the `option` tag instead of its `text` just replace this

> var y = x.options[i].text;

to this

> var y = x.options[i].value;

Comment: For more additional questions regarding this visit here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216885/overwrite-duplicate-value-in-an-array-javascript#25216924. I'd made a question relative to yours.