# Overwrite duplicate value in an array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, duplicates

I have read some partially solutions on my problem but unfortunately I've come up for questioning. So here's my question. I have an array `var = results[1,2,2,3,1,3]`. I have to print/echo all the values and the final values should be display the value of `1,2,3`. I've read about finding values that has a duplicate but this might not work on mine since it only returns **duplicate values**. I've read about filtering **unique values** but of course it will only show me a unique value and won't show me the others. And one of the comments there suggests this and absolutely maybe an exact solution:

> _.uniq([1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4]);
>
> => [1, 2, 3, 4]

the link is [HERE...](http://lodash.com/docs#uniq)

But I don't know how to use it correctly. Is it applicable to my problem?

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3e8tcv02/5/) anyway.

Comment: This is answered here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array

Comment: I've read that and it's too complicated. Mine just a little bit simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the very simple implementation using js

```
var getfruits = [1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3];
var uniq = [];
for (var i = 0; i < getfruits.length; i++) {
    if(uniq.indexOf(getfruits[i])==-1)
        uniq.push(getfruits[i]);
};

console.log(uniq);
```

And you have to just add `lo-dash` in your fiddle.

[**FIXED FIDDLE WITH LO-DASH**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/3e8tcv02/9/)

Comment: @Alexdn here is your fixed fiddle with lo-dash, I've updated in my answer also. http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/3e8tcv02/9/

Comment: One more sir. This is actually the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/frLdf32L/79/. Why displays me `1,2,2`? instead of `1,2,3`?

Comment: If you notice, I want to store all values taken from `option` tag to an array. Then make again a new array to store the filtered duplicate value. And for final step is to append a textbox that has a value of those three. And I think I can do that. If the last problem will be solve.

Comment: include jQuery it says `$` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    var getfruits = [1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3];
    var newfruits = [];
    $.each(getfruits, function (i, el) {
        if ($.inArray(el, newfruits) === -1) newfruits.push(el);
    });
    console.log(newfruits)
    alert(newfruits[0]);
    alert(newfruits[1]);
    alert(newfruits[2]);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3e8tcv02/7/)

Comment: Very simple solution. Thanks sir :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3];
var newarr = [];
$.each(arr, function (index, element) {
    if ($.inArray(element, newarr) < 0) newarr.push(element);
});

alert(newarr[0]);
alert(newarr[1]);
alert(newarr[2]);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uyg8dgn7/)